# After Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade, where is my network config at?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I recently upgraded my desktop from Ubuntu 16.04 to Ubuntu 18.04 and can't figure out wth my network config went. I get that 18.04 uses *netplan* now, but `/etc/netplan` is empty as well as `/etc/network/interfaces` yet somehow the system has the correct IP addresses on the correct interfaces. I googled a bit and found some *netplan* examples but would really like to know where the current config is kept in case conflicts arise. Where is this kept on an upgrade?

Comment: Did you read the Release Notes for Ubuntu 18.04? `https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/`?

Comment: Can you be more specific, please? I know `netplan.io` is the new way but that link also states _The installer will generate a configuration file for netplan.io in the /etc/netplan directory._ . This location is empty on my system. `networkctl list` does show my links but states they are  `unmanaged` with no clue as to **where** this information has moved to.

Comment: Is there content under `/run/systemd/network`? My machine has several `*.network` and `*.netdev` files here. I thought `netplan` is essentially like a wrapper around networkd, and therefore configurations are written out here (after `netplan` does it's thing).

Comment: There are two directories (`links` and `leases`) under `/run/systemd/netif/` but no `/run/systemd/network` directory. The directories under `netif` are empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link that waitinator sent you, but it is not totally clear.

In the same paragraph on the [release notes for networking](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/BionicBeaver/ReleaseNotes#New_since_16.04_LTS), we see:

> Desktop users will see their system fully managed via NetworkManager
> as it has been the case in previous releases

This means the /etc/netplan dir is empty, you have to go to the desktop and search for "Advanced Network Configuration" and in that GUI you will modify your config.

If you really want to do it manually, you need to [turn off network manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1091653/how-do-i-disable-network-manager-permanently) and then edit netplan.

Comment: The system is remote and I don't have xrdp or vnc running so can't seem to interact with `NetworkManager`. I did use the link you offered to disable it however and then configured netplan. It seems to be working now as `networkctl list` shows my devices with hot links as _routable_ _configured_. Thank you for the help!